# VisualStudio Code autocomplete not working for JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio-code

vs code autocomplete when I write a script in HTML itself but when I make a separate file for javascript it does not work
[image: In the first image it recommend when I type "doc"]

[image: In the second image it does not show any javascript function.]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript isn't necessarily used with an HTML DOM, so when writing a separate js file, VS Code does not assume a DOM to be present by default, and it therefore does not show you autocompletions for that.